# How to calculate fiscal week start from date in SQL

Tags: sql, database, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have got a .csv file which has two date columns. Day which is just a date and Week (Fscl) which is start of the week date.

**One week example from the .csv file:**

| Week (Fscl) | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-13 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-14 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-15 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-16 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-17 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-18 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-19 |

I usually calculate start of the week by using `date_trunc` function but results are completly different than what I am getting from .csvs:

| Week (Fscl) | Day | date_trunc('week', day) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-13 | 2021-11-08 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-14 | 2021-11-08 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-15 | 2021-11-15 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-16 | 2021-11-15 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-17 | 2021-11-15 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-18 | 2021-11-15 |
| 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-19 | 2021-11-15 |

I am wondering what's the logic behind fiscal week and why dates between `2021-11-13` and `2021-11-19` belong to week number `47` (`2021-11-22` - `2021-11-28`).
Is it possible to replicate this logic in SQL? Preferably Snowflake SQL

Comment: It's your data. We can't tell you why November 22nd would have anything at all to do with the 8th of November. It also makes no sense to me. Perhaps if you have more sample data from which we can derive some pattern we can help out.

Comment: Ask owner of that data what those two columns *actually* indicate and if they are calculated correctly.

Comment: Got it, I assumed that fiscal calendar was some strange kind of calendar like nrf454 where weeks are numbered differently.